# Why would creating an object of a class that implements runnable from worker thread throw an exception?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, nullpointerexception

I have two class:

MainActivity.java
ClientThread.java

ClientThread.java looks like this:

```
//
// client thread class
//
public class ClientThread implements Runnable
{
    View _V;

    public ClientThread(Context ctx)
    {
        Log.d("", "Step 1...");
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        Log.d("", "Step 2...");
        _V = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
        Log.d("", "Step 3...");
    }

    @Override
    public void run() 
    {   
        // validate server ip
        if (MainActivity.SERVER_IP != "")
        {
         try 
        {               
/* do socket stuff here...  */                                  
        }
            /* 
             catch exceptions here...
             */
        else
        {
           setStatus("Wrong IP!!");
        }           
    }

    //
    //  message handler
    //
    public void setStatus(String msg)
    {           
      // do status stuff here e.g. setting textview
    }

    //
    //  message handler for status edit box
    //
    Handler h = new Handler()
    {                                                   
        //EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.status_text);
        TextView tv = (TextView)_V.findViewById(R.id.status_text);

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg_obj) {
            String s = (String)msg_obj.obj;

            tv.setText(s);

        }
    };      
}
```

Then from MainActivity.java I am doing this:

```
public Context ctx;

TextView status;    

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ctx = this;
    ... other stuff
}

//  on connect
//  we create a new thread to connect to server
//
public void onConnect(View view) 
{                   
    try
    {
    new Thread(new ClientThread(ctx)).start();  <== creating new object is issue!
    }
    catch (IllegalStateException is)
    {
        is.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Here is the error printed:

```
03-12 22:00:55.826: E/AndroidRuntime(1897): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-12 22:00:55.826: E/AndroidRuntime(1897):     at com.example.helloapp.ClientThread$1.<init>(ClientThread.java:101)
```

**What I tried:**

when I put the ClientThread class inside the MainActivity class things are good. But I want to separate the class in its own file. Why can't I call it the way I am doing and what is the right way?

Comment: Where is ctx coming from in MainActivity?  And if that's the activity, why aren't you using this as the context?  Because the most likely problem to me is that you're calling getSystemService on null.

Comment: i have updated my question to show ctx.

Comment: Which of your "Step 1/2/3..." messages get logged?

Comment: actually none and this is what is bugging me. I should mention (not sure if it matters), when I was creating this new ClientThread.java file in eclipse I left the base class section as java.lang.object.

Answer (score 1):

The NPE is clearly because `ctx` was null, but `ctx = this;` etc. doesn't make much sense. If `ctx` is a self-valued instance variable, it doesn't even need to exist at all. Just remove it and use `this`, or `MainActivity.this` throughout, as appropriate.

Comment: i did try new Thread(new ClientThread(this)).start(); but still getting same issue.